# Pure CSS crossfade gallery with any number of pictures

Tags: css

I have a slideshow where pictures crossfade automatically in a loop. It is set so that 3 pictures are scrolling.

Demo in Codepen (http://codepen.io/lopis/pen/VYRoKE)

```
<section class="crossfade">
  <article class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/people" alt="" />
  </article>
  <article class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats" alt="" />
  </article>
  <article class="slide">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports" alt="" />
  </article>
</section>
```

The CSS:

```
$slideDuration: 4; // seconds
$slideNum: 3;

@mixin loop($name, $duration, $delay) {
  -webkit-animation: $name #{$duration}s #{$delay}s infinite;
  -moz-animation: $name #{$duration}s #{$delay}s infinite;
  animation: $name #{$duration}s #{$delay}s infinite;
}

@mixin slide() {
  @for $i from 1 through $slideNum {
    .slide:nth-child( #{$i} ) {
      @include loop( crossfade, ($slideNum * $slideDuration), (($i - 1) * $slideDuration) );
    }
  }
}

@mixin keyframes() {

  @-webkit-keyframes crossfade {
    0% {
      opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
      opacity:1;
    }
    33% {
      opacity:0;
    }
    86% {
      opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity:1;
    }
  }

  @keyframes crossfade {
    0% {
      opacity:1;
    }
    25% {
      opacity:1;
    }
    33% {
      opacity:0;
    }
    86% {
      opacity:0;
    }
    100% {
      opacity:1;
    }
  }
}


.crossfade {
  position: relative;
}
.slide {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
.slide:first-child {
  position: static;
}

@include slide();

@include keyframes();
```

Is there a way to make an animation like this that would work with any number of slides using just CSS?

Edit: I understand that such dynamism is not intended in CSS but you can have *some* dynamic content, like by using `calc()`, etc.

Some libraries, as the one suggested in the comments, allow the use of mixins for this task. This is not what I'm looking for as it requires a rebuild of the source.

Comment: I've created a SASS mixin for this task:  http://www.fabriziocalderan.it/css3slideshow/

Comment: I'll test it in a bit, but does it require that we rebuild sass every time?

Comment: the amount of images has to be passed as a parameter of the mixin, keyframes need to know when the opacity must be animated

Comment: That's what I thought. It is not a solution then.

Comment: No it is not. Even when CSS accepts dynamic values for calculation, like the `calc()` attribute, you are unable to pass the number of images in the DOM over to the `@keyframe` property, for example. That means that you will have to manually rewrite the keyframes when you have a new image, and there is no other way than using a CSS preprocessor, or JS.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this using only CSS, using a content responsive technique

Let's set a time for each slide of 2 seconds.

We need to set a staggered delay for every nth child of 2 seconds. That is easily acieved with nth-child.

Now, we need to increase the duration of the transition depending on the number of elements. Using this [technique](http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/) we achieve this easily.

The third issue is managing the fade-out. In the standard approach, that would involve changing the keyframes changing point, and it would be cumbersome. The trick to get this working with much less code, is to make a z-index movement in the animation itself. The elements are moving backward, and then we don't care about their opacity anymore

Example set only for 3 posible number of elements:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.element {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: anim 6s infinite;
}


.element:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: lightyellow;
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.element:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
.element:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: pink;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}
.element:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: lightblue;
  animation-delay: 6s;
}
.element:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: coral;
  animation-delay: 8s;
}
.element:nth-child(6) {
  background-color: aliceblue;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
.element:nth-child(7) {
  background-color: burlywood;
  animation-delay: 12s;
}
.element:nth-child(8) {
  background-color: bisque;
  animation-delay: 14s;
}
.element:nth-child(9) {
  background-color: beige;
  animation-delay: 16s;
}

.element:nth-last-child(3):first-child, 
.element:nth-last-child(3):first-child ~ .element {
  animation-duration: 6s;
}

.element:nth-last-child(6):first-child, 
.element:nth-last-child(6):first-child ~ .element {
  animation-duration: 12s;
}

.element:nth-last-child(9):first-child, 
.element:nth-last-child(9):first-child ~ .element {
  animation-duration: 18s;
}

@keyframes anim {
  0% { opacity: 0; z-index: 100;}
  15% { opacity: 1;}
  50% { opacity: 1;}
  100% { opacity: 0; z-index: 1;}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">ONE</div>
    <div class="element">TWO</div>
    <div class="element">THREE</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">ONE</div>
    <div class="element">TWO</div>
    <div class="element">THREE</div>
    <div class="element">FOUR</div>
    <div class="element">FIVE</div>
    <div class="element">SIX</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="element">ONE</div>
    <div class="element">TWO</div>
    <div class="element">THREE</div>
    <div class="element">FOUR</div>
    <div class="element">FIVE</div>
    <div class="element">SIX</div>
    <div class="element">SEVEN</div>
    <div class="element">EIGHT</div>
    <div class="element">NINE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, that's clever! I'll try this when I have the time.

Comment: 4 years later this code snippet is still extremely relevant. This pen will let you use the code with an unknown number of images, custom fade-in/fade-out time and custom delay between each slide: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VRLOKz

Comment: Guys, thanks for your explanation!

Why do we need to use the number 100 of z-index?
@LuBre, thanks for your solution :)

Comment: @OleksandrLunov It can be any number high enough. As the animation advances, the z-index will get lower, and decrease to 99, 98 ...  Since it is an integer, you need to be sure that 100 / number of slides is greater then 1. If you set it only to 10, it could fail for a large number of slides

Comment: @vals thanks, now I've understood. Stay safe and healthy!